# Result set of laravel data in proper format

Tags: php, json, laravel

i am using laravel to make an API that queries a database and show a simple output. Now my query goes like this:

```
$name = new TableName() ; //An object which is storing tablename
$result=DB::table($name->getMyTableName()) // Getting the tablename
        ->select()
        ->where('id','=',1)->orWhere('id','=',2)
        ->get();
```

Now this will fetch two records with id 1 and 2 and when I pass them through my controller, the json out put comes like this:

```
[
{
"id": "1",
"question": "This is",
"question_main": "sample1",
"option_1": "opt_1",
"option_2": "opt_1",
"option_3": "opt_1",
"option_4": "opt_1",
},
{
"id": "2",
"question": "This is",
"question_main": "sample2",
"option_1": "opt_1",
"option_2": "opt_2",
"option_3": "opt_3",
"option_4": "opt_4",

}
]
```

Now what I want is instead of option, i have something like this:

option :

```
{ 
            1=>"opt_1",
            2=>"opt_2",
            3=>"opt_3",
            4=>"opt_4",
 }
```

Now what i tried is this:

```
foreach ($result as $results)
        {
            $final_result= array_add($final_result, 'id', $results->id);
            $final_result= array_add($final_result, 'question', $results->question);
            $final_result= array_add($final_result, 'question_main', $results->question_main);
            $final_result= array_add($final_result, 'options', array(
                [
                    1 => $results->option_1,
                    2 => $results->option_2,
                    3 => $results->option_3,
                    4 => $results->option_4,
                ]
            ));

        }
        return json_encode($final_result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This pretty much solves the problem however as you might have figured out key-value pair can have unique key so it will just store id=2 (the latter). I am pretty much confused on what to follow. I tried Multi dimensional array but i think i couldn't get the concept right on that.Any suggestions, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following using the key in your foreach:

```
$final_result = [];
foreach ($result as $key => $results)
{
    $final_result[$key] = [
        'id' => $results->id,
        'question' => $results->question,
        'question_main' => $results->question_main,
        'options' => [
            1 => $results->option_1,
            2 => $results->option_2,
            3 => $results->option_3,
            4 => $results->option_4
        ]
    ];

}
return json_encode($final_result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: It was spot on. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

This would do the desired.

```
    $arrayToBePrinted = [];
    foreach ($result as $results)
    {
        $final_result= array_add($final_result, 'id', $results->id);
        $final_result= array_add($final_result, 'question', $results->question);
        $final_result= array_add($final_result, 'question_main', $results->question_main);
        $final_result= array_add($final_result, 'options', array(
            [
                1 => $results->option_1,
                2 => $results->option_2,
                3 => $results->option_3,
                4 => $results->option_4,
            ]
        ));

     $arrayToBePrinted[] = $final_result;

    }
    return json_encode($arrayToBePrinted,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: you are doing the same mistake where i was stuck, the $arrayToBePrinted will just store the last id nd will just display it twice , anyways thanks for the help :)

Comment: `$arrayToBePrinted[]` is going to **append** `$final_result` to it. So it should be working.

Comment: @user3103915 exactly what IvankaTodorova said. It does append and so should work.

Comment: i did check and it was showing me the same thing twice, i will still check again and will let u know .